# Django: TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/ (Source Does Not Exist)

Tags: python, django, templates, authentication

I'm trying to get into Django and I'm following tutorials here and there. I'm trying to add a login page to the polling app from the official Django tutorial but even though I'm following [this simple tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html) to the letter I get the `TemplateDoesNotExist error`. From what I can tell though, Django is looking for `login.html` in the correct directory and gives the message Source doesn't exist.

**My file structure:**

```
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── secvot
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── admin
│   │   │   └── base_site.html
│   │   └── registration
│   │       ├── login.html
│   │       └── logout.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
└── voting
    ├── admin.py
    ├── admin.pyc
    ├── apps.py
    ├── apps.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
    │   ├── 0002_auto_20180301_2354.py
    │   ├── 0002_auto_20180301_2354.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __init__.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── models.pyc
    ├── static
    │   └── voting
    │       ├── images
    │       │   └── background.gif
    │       └── style.css
    ├── templates
    │   └── voting
    │       ├── detail.html
    │       ├── index.html
    │       └── results.html
    ├── tests.py
    ├── tests.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.pyc
    ├── views.py
    └── views.pyc
```

**settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'voting.apps.VotingConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'secvot.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
```

secvot/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}, name='login.html'),
    url(r'^logout/', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^polls/', include('voting.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**login.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password">
        </p>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and part of the error page:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/
registration/login.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
registration/login.html
Exception Location: /home/kostis/.virtualenvs/secretvoting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in select_template, line 53
Python Executable:  /home/kostis/.virtualenvs/secretvoting/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/kostis/PycharmProjects/secvot',
 '/home/kostis/.virtualenvs/secretvoting/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/kostis/.virtualenvs/secretvoting/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/kostis/.virtualenvs/secretvoting/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/kostis/.virtualenvs/secretvoting/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/kostis/.virtualenvs/secretvoting/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/kostis/.virtualenvs/secretvoting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/kostis/.virtualenvs/secretvoting/lib/python2.7/site-packages']


Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/kostis/PycharmProjects/secvot/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/kostis/PycharmProjects/secvot/voting/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/kostis/.virtualenvs/secretvoting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/kostis/.virtualenvs/secretvoting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
```

From what I can tell Django tries to load the correct template, looks into the correct folder but shows the error "Source does not exist" even though the template is there.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see `BASE_DIR` setting in your settings.py. The error `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/kostis/PycharmProjects/secvot/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)` make me think that django is looking the wrong dir.

Comment: But the directory you mentioned is the correct directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

This tells Django to look for a `templates` directory in your project directory (the one containing `manage.py`. However your templates directory is in your inner project directory (the one containing `settings.py`.

You could fix it by doing one of the following:

1. Move the templates directory
2. Change the `DIRS` settings to point to the current location of the templates directory.

   ```
   'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'secvot', 'templates')],
   ```
3. Add `secvot` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` so that the `app_directories` loader finds the templates directory. If you do this, you can change `DIRS` to `[]`.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, but if you look at the error page you'll see this:

Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/kostis/PycharmProjects/secvot/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)

So Django looks at the correct path where my template is but still doesn't load it. why?

Comment: You’re not reading the error message or my answer closely enough. Your template directory isn’t at that path, it’s at  `/home/kostis/PycharmProjects/secvot/secvot/templates/registration/login.html`.

Comment: Omg. You're right. I totally missed that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

## Its a spelling mistake !

in my case the error was

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist

Exception Value: blog/blog_form.html

and the weird part is i din't even created this blog_form.html file.

what was that silly mistake then?

i mentioned template_name as tempplate_name (see the spellings) in the views.py file.

it tooked me more than 30 minutes to find this mistake because most people have a habit of reading quickly (instead of reading letter by letter). Also i couldn't find that blog_form.html file (which don't even exist and most of the time wasted beacuse of this file). So i suggest you to go back and find that spelling mistake. It worked for me i hope it will work for you as well beacuse i know how frustrating it is.